# Blender Error "Not able to read the .blend file"

Tags: error, linux

I was working in blender in Linux Mint, while i was saving the file my pc got hang.The pc specs are good enough to that much work in blender.I had to then Shutdown the pc through the power button.Then when i switch on the pc blender showed up an error like "Not able to read the .blend file" and all the data in the file got lost.

Comment: If your computer crashes mid file write, then the file is corrupt / incomplete and can't be read. There isn't anything we or Blender can do about this.

Comment: If the file is unrecoverable and you had "autosave" enabled in the preferences, you can still find a copy in File > Recover > Autosave. Hopefully you only lost a few minutes of work.

Comment: Auto-save recovery is of course an option, in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: had you saved even once?

Comment: I do save the file after every minute by CTRL-S and when i tried to recover the auto saved file from the default tmp folder, there were no file except from a quit.blend file that i didnt even made and when i opened the quit.blend file it showed the same error mentioned above.Thanks for responding back!